# I am looking for the IDPID or the Sign-On URL for our Demo site

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an Azure SSO for our Demo page and I need the Sign On URL. I am looking for the IDPID portion of the URL. I had gone into the application and not finding where it is located there. Support has not been able to help me.

I don't have the info so can't try.

Comment: Why not ask whoever developed that application? Shouldn't they know these URLs?

Comment: This was the link they sent me for their developer to respond..  <shrug>

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From the [MS SSO guide for DocuSign SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/saas-apps/docusign-tutorial):

In this tutorial, you'll learn how to integrate DocuSign with Microsoft Entra ID. When you integrate DocuSign with Microsoft Entra ID, you can:

Use Microsoft Entra ID to control who has access to DocuSign.
Enable automatic sign-in to DocuSign for your users through their Microsoft Entra accounts.
Manage your accounts in one central location: the Azure portal.
Prerequisites
To get started, you need the following items:

A Microsoft Entra subscription. If you don't have a subscription, you can get a free account.
A DocuSign subscription that's single sign-on (SSO) enabled.
Control over your domain DNS. This is needed to claim domain on DocuSign.
Note

This integration is also available to use from Microsoft Entra US Government Cloud environment. You can find this application in the Microsoft Entra US Government Cloud Application Gallery and configure it in the same way as you do from public cloud.

Scenario description
In this tutorial, you'll configure and test Microsoft Entra SSO in a test environment to verify that:

DocuSign supports service provider SP initiated SSO.

DocuSign supports just-in-time user provisioning.

DocuSign supports automatic user provisioning.

Add DocuSign from the gallery
To configure the integration of DocuSign into Microsoft Entra ID, you must add DocuSign from the gallery to your list of managed SaaS apps:

Sign in to the Microsoft Entra admin center as at least a Cloud Application Administrator.
Browse to Identity > Applications > Enterprise applications > New application.
In the Add from the gallery section, type DocuSign in the search box.
Select DocuSign from the results panel and then add the app. Wait a few seconds while the app is added to your tenant.
Alternatively, you can also use the Enterprise App Configuration Wizard. In this wizard, you can add an application to your tenant, add users/groups to the app, assign roles, as well as walk through the SSO configuration as well. Learn more about Microsoft 365 wizards.

Alternatively, you can also use the Enterprise App Configuration Wizard. In this wizard, you can add an application to your tenant, add users/groups to the app, assign roles, as well as walk through the SSO configuration as well. You can learn more about O365 wizards here.

Configure and test Microsoft Entra SSO for DocuSign
Configure and test Microsoft Entra SSO with DocuSign by using a test user named B.Simon. For SSO to work, you must establish a link relationship between a Microsoft Entra user and the corresponding user in DocuSign.

To configure and test Microsoft Entra SSO with DocuSign, perform the following steps:

Configure Microsoft Entra SSO so that your users can use this feature.
Create a Microsoft Entra test user to test Microsoft Entra single sign-on with B.Simon.
Assign the Microsoft Entra test user to enable B.Simon to use Microsoft Entra single sign-on.
Configure DocuSign SSO to configure the single sign-on settings on the application side.
Create a DocuSign test user to generate a counterpart of B.Simon in DocuSign that's linked to the Microsoft Entra representation of the user.
Test SSO to verify that the configuration works.

Configure Microsoft Entra SSO
To enable Microsoft Entra SSO in the Azure portal, follow these steps:

Sign in to the Microsoft Entra admin center as at least a Cloud Application Administrator.

Browse to Identity > Applications > Enterprise applications > DocuSign application integration page, find the Manage section, and then select single sign-on.

On the Select a single sign-on method page, select SAML.

On the Set up single sign-on with SAML page, select the pencil icon for Basic SAML Configuration to edit the settings.

Edit Basic SAML Configuration

In the Basic SAML Configuration section, perform the following steps:

a. In the Identifier (Entity ID) textbox, type a URL using the following pattern:

https://.docusign.com/organizations//saml2

b. In the Reply URL textbox, type a URL using one of the following patterns:

Reply URL
Production :
https://.docusign.com/organizations//saml2/login/
https://.docusign.net/SAML/
QA Instance :
https://.docusign.com/organizations/saml2
c. In the Sign on URL textbox, type a URL using the following pattern:

https://.docusign.com/organizations//saml2/login/sp/